# Rendering HTML in jade email templates with readFileSync encoded as utf8

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to send a jade email template but it's currently rendering everything as a string instead of HTML in the actual email. I tried looking for other encoding types for `fs.readFileSync` but am not sure if that's what I should even be changing.

Calling the template here:

```
var emailTemplate = jade.compile(fs.readFileSync('./views/email/new_user.jade', 'utf8'));
    var html = emailTemplate({
      confirmCode: 233,
      name: params.name,
      siteName: config.siteName
      siteLogo: config.siteLogo
    });
```

The template:

```
div(style='width: 300px; margin: 0 auto')
  div(style='text-align: center')
    img(src='#{siteLogo}')
  | Hi #{name},
  p
    | Welcome to #{siteName}! You can now vote on submissions and leave comments.
    | In order for your submissions to be public, please confirm your account by
    | clicking the confirmation link below
  div(style='background-color: #fafafa; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-right: none; border-left: none; display: block; font-weight: bold; line-height: 35px; height: 35px; text-align: center; width:    100%;')
    a(href='http://localhost/users/confirm/') Confirm your account
```

Output (in my email):

```
<div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto"><div style="text-align: center"><img src="http://localhost/site_logo.png"/></div>Hi USER,<p>Welcome to SITENAME! You can now vote on submissions and leave comments. In order for your submissions to be public, please confirm your account by clicking the confirmation link below</p><div style="background-color: #fafafa; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-right: none; border-left: none; display: block; font-weight: bold; line-height: 35px; height: 35px; text-align: center; width: 100%;"><a href="http://localhost/users/confirm/">Confirm your account</a></div></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem a bit more as it seems like everything is working? The template has worked fine by the looks of it.

Comment: @AndyD it just spits out the string into the email body and doesn't actually render the HTML, so I'm seeing all the `<div style="width..` markup.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is with how you're sending the email not with the template code at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're having this problem because the `Content-Type` of your e-mail is not `text/html`. Try doing so.

Comment: That was it exactly. Ended up switching to using the sendgrid npm module instead of the Mailer module and specified ```html``` as the optional parameter and now it works.